# Seed sonar with junit and integration-test report(jacoco.exec) from maven

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a project, for which I have already have generated jacoco.exec report files using jacoco plugin for junit test case and integration test.

This is the maven properties I use for sonar:

```
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/target/it/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/junit/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<!-- Tells Sonar to run the unit tests -->
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<!-- Tells Sonar to use JaCoCo as the code coverage tool -->
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
```

I created profile for sonar like below:

```
<profile>
  <id>sonar-run</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar
    </sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>123qwe</sonar.jdbc.password>
    <sonar.host.url>
      http://localhost:9000/
    </sonar.host.url>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

The problem I face is, I am able to see the unit test code-coverage in sonar, but I am not able to see the integration-test code-coverage.

I run the maven command many ways some thing like this:

```
mvn verify -P sonar-run sonar:sonar
mvn verify -P sonar-run sonar:sonar -Dtests=false
mvn clean install -P sonar-run sonar:sonar
```

but still I am not able to see the integration-test code coverage in sonar, am I missing some step?

I use sonar 4.0, java-7.

**Note:** For us the jacoco.exec files are already generated in some other run, I just want to seed them to sonar if possible, this way we will gain some performance improvement.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying and editing the question accordingly. Are you using a multi-module project?

Comment: Yep it is multi-module maven project...but that is not my concern...

Answer (score 0):

We are also defining 2 separate variables in our pom, containing the path to the `jacoco.exec` we want to see generated for normal tests and integration tests:

```
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
```

---

We have 2 seperate profiles (hooking into `prepare-agent` and `prepare-agent-integration` respectively):

```
<profile>
        <id>jacoco-ut</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                                <append>true</append>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Code coverage with Jacoco on integration-tests -->
    <profile>
        <id>jacoco-it</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent-for-it</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                                <append>true</append>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                              <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                          </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

This is how we run both unit tests and integration-tests and finally send results to sonar:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Pdefault,jacoco-ut
mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent-integration install -Pintegration-tests,jacoco-it -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
mvn sonar:sonar -Pdefault -Dsonar.host.url=http://XX -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports  -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DsonarPassword=XX -DsonarJdbcPassword=XX -Psonar
```

So we call `prepare-agent install` using the `jacoco-ut` profile and the `prepare-agent-integration install` using the `jacoco-it` profile.

Comment: I think, you run the intergration-test / junit test, For me, those are already ran somewhere else in some other job(parallel), I don't want to run them here, i just want to get the jacoco.exec file, and then seed them to sonar. Just some performance improvement I don't want to run them again, do you think this can be achieved?

Comment: So Just to update :- So here is how I fixed the issue. The sonar server version we are running updated to 5.5(after that version Java-8 is required), i was able to seed 2 jacoco files, one for junit and one for integration-test. It generates same code coverage in sonarquebe as previous.